# Ping Failed - com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: database, eclipse

Trying to connect to through database development(data source explorer) in eclipse and during test connection i found ping failed.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

```
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)

at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)

at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)

at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)

at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)

at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:328)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)

at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)

at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)

at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)

at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)

at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)

at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)

at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)

at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)

at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)

at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)

... 13 more
```

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

```
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)

at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)

at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)

at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)

... 16 more
```

Comment: http://www.bhaveshthaker.com/33/database-development-using-the-eclipse-ide-mysql-with-eclipse-data-tools-platform-in-java/

Comment: using the above site as references but no results